# How to read from txtfile and then pass the information to another class c#

Tags: c#, file-io

I use following code to store data in an array, then print it out.

```
Person[] people = {new Person( "Loki", "Lo", "Asgard", 2050),
                              new Person( "Thor", "Th", "Asgard", 2050),
                              new Person( "Iron", "Man", "Il", 4050),
                              new Person( "The", "Hulk", "Green", 1970)};
```

Now I want to read from a textline with those information and use the same array. How to?

The txt file looks like this

```
The Hulk Green 1970
Iron Man Il 4050
Thor Th Asgard 2050
Loki Lo Asgard 2050
```

I'm thinking about storing the words in a string array and then use [0], [1] and so on for each word. But a loop would cause a problem because I only want to use one "person". Any suggestions?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout There are only 2 questions he hasn't accepted an answer for and this is one of them... Might want to check how many questions 80% is computed from.

Comment: how is this related to wpf??

Comment: this is in the code behind file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution without using Linq

```
Person[] people= new Person[4];
using(var file = System.IO.File.OpenText(_LstFilename))
{
   int j=0;
 while (!file.EndOfStream)
    {
        String line = file.ReadLine();

        // ignore empty lines
        if (line.Length > 0)
        {    

            string[] words = line.Split(' ');
             Person per= new Person(words[0], words[1], words[2], Convert.ToInt32(words[3]));

             people[j]=per;
             j++

        }

}
```

Comment: You may want to check `words.Length >= 4` to make sure a short line doesn't cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`  No clue if that would help for your assignment or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a `Person` constructor that takes a "line" of data and parse it accordingly.

Then you can just do this:

```
var people = File.ReadLines("yourFile.txt")
                 .Select(line => new Person(line))
                 .ToArray();
```

If you don't want the extra constructor:

```
var people = File.ReadLines("yourFile.txt")
                 .Select(line => line.Split())
                 .Select(items => new Person(item[0], item[1], item[2], Convert.ToInt32(item[3]))
                 .ToArray();
```

You should note that neither solution provided here has good exception handling.

Comment: Thanks Austin! I do prefer not using LINQ, because of the assignment.